# How to sum multiple repeated values just once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A/B are 2 different part numbers.

Column O is the value for those.

Each value in column O is being repeated multiple times.
[image: Data]

**What I am looking for** - I am looking for a formula which can help sum all the values but just counting them as once. For example it should be 2+20 irrespective of how many times it is being repeated with respect to both Column A and B
[image: Result]

**What I tried** - I tried a combination of SUMIF and SUMIFS but didn't work. It would just sum all the values.

Thanks

Comment: If you have Excel365 then something like `=sum(unique(O:O))`

Comment: More like `=sum(xlookup(unique(b:b),b:b,o:o,0,0))`

Comment: @findwindowThat is the point, I do not want repeating sums. Yes it was exactly that.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes I have 365, let me give it a try

Comment: @P.b it should take into account both Column A and B because one column is a primary and the other is secondary

Comment: `=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A:A,B:B,O:O)),0,3))`?

Comment: The replace both `b:b` for `a:a&"|"&b:b`: `=sum(xlookup(unique(a:a&"|"&b:b),a:a&"|"&b:b,o:o,0,0))`

Comment: Let me give it a try @ScottCraner #@P.b

Comment: Or even `=SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(A:O,1,2,15)),,2))` or `=SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A:B,O:O)),,2))`

Comment: @P.b getting aggregated sums

Comment: @JvdV let me test that out

Comment: It's essentially @ScottCraner his suggestion in the form of new BETA functions you may not yet have access to.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted, aggregated sum?

Comment: @P.b I do but not every repeating value. In the above example, 2 and 20 are repeated many times but in reality based off of tribal knowledge, I know they just count once. So I want a formula which counts those 1 time. So it would become 2+20 instead of aggregate all the 2s and 20s

Comment: I understand now. Scott's commented Index/Unique/Choose solution is brilliant

Comment: I still don't really understand the logic of the values being repeated (as it appears) a random number of times and then the value in column O changes. Could you explain that? (Could we possibly skip values with our solution that should've been counted if the value changes to the same (for instance in row 2-4 it's value 2 and row 5-10 it's 24 and row 11 it's back to 2 again. Would that count as 2+4 or 2+4+2?).

Comment: Sorry for reaching back a bit later. Yes, that is how the system puts it but it doesn't mean it is happening over and over. To answer your question, that is dependent on the part number. If the repeating value is for the same part number then no, we would not count it. So at the end it will still be 2+24 because the 2 that got repeated is still for the same part number